# Create a scheduled task to run after a service is started using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I've looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/502160/run-a-scheduled-task-after-a-windows-service-is-started) where it's shown how to create a trigger to run after a service is started, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this via Powershell.

[New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821(v=wps.620).aspx) seems to only support time-based triggers, but not based on an event, like a service starting. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` unfortunately does not have a way to create event driven triggers. The PS community has [requested that this be implemented](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11088309-missing-trigger-options-in-new-scheduledtasktrigge).

We should be able to combine the XML you're working with with code that [creates tasks using .NET](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1030490-task-scheduler-vb-script-help?page=1#entry-4758670). Just replace the user, pass, and service name.

```
$taskRunAsuser = "domain\user"
$taskRunAsUserPwd = "password"
$Service = new-object -ComObject ("Schedule.Service")
$Service.Connect($env:computername)
$RootFolder = $Service.GetFolder("\")
$TaskDefinition = $Service.NewTask(0)
$settings = $taskDefinition.Settings
$settings.Enabled = $true
$settings.StartWhenAvailable = $true
$settings.Hidden = $false
$Triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
$Trigger = $Triggers.Create(0)
#$Trigger.Id = '4800'
$Trigger.Subscription = "<QueryList> 
<Query Id='0'> 
   <Select Path='System'> 
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='param1'] and (Data='YOUR SERVICE NAME')]] 
      and
      *[EventData[Data[@Name='param2'] and (Data='running')]] 
    </Select> 
</Query> 
</QueryList>"
$Trigger.Enabled = $true
$Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
$Action.Path = 'ping.exe'
$Action.Arguments = '8.8.8.8 > C:\ping.log'
$rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition('Test',$TaskDefinition,6,$taskRunAsUser,$taskRunAsUserPwd,1)
```

Comment: Amazing example, really appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I got syntax and run-time error