# Notification when specific service started in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, services, notifications

Is there any way to config Windows to show notification just after specific service started?

By notification I mean any solution/way that user get notify when specific service start running.

Comment: Use Process Hacker: https://github.com/processhacker2/processhacker.git

Answer (score 1):

You can create a schedule task that will be triggered when a specific service starts. When creating the task, you can specify your query (I don't remember if there's a specific event or you need to edit the XML for that).

---

**EDIT:** I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/502229/321990) that explains how to do it.

Comment: I did same as mentioned link says, but task doesn't start when service started.

Comment: You've tried with the service name or display name?

Comment: Both (but not at same time, I don't know anything about that kind of XML)

Comment: You can try looking [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa383609), it's the detailed schema of that XML.

Comment: Is your selected path correct? In the example it's `system`

Comment: Thanks for helping me, the `Path to executable` shows `system32` folder, so should I put `system32` instead of `system` as path?